# How do I call Peekable::next based on the result of Peekable::peek?

Tags: rust

```
use std::iter::Peekable;

pub trait AdvanceWhile<I: Iterator> {
    fn advance_while<P>(&mut self, predicate: P)
    where
        P: Fn(&I::Item) -> bool;
}

impl<I: Iterator> AdvanceWhile<I> for Peekable<I> {
    fn advance_while<P>(&mut self, predicate: P)
    where
        P: Fn(&I::Item) -> bool,
    {
        while let Some(val) = self.peek() {
            if predicate(val) {
                self.next();
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=22b20f6da45f344c0eeeda2a1ba88ec8&version=nightly&backtrace=0)

Error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:16:17
   |
14 |         while let Some(val) = self.peek() {
   |                               ---- first mutable borrow occurs here
15 |             if predicate(val) {
16 |                 self.next();
   |                 ^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
...
20 |         }
   |         - first borrow ends here
```

Comment: This was [cross-posted to the Users Forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-do-i-work-with-the-borrow-checker-in-this-case/6005?u=shepmaster).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Lukas Kalbertodt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37508306/5189607) already said, this is a limitation of the borrow checker. Here I would like to show a more readable version:

```
fn advance_while<P>(&mut self, predicate: P)
    where P: Fn(&I::Item) -> bool 
{
    while let Some(true) = self.peek().map(&predicate) {
        self.next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Typical case of lexical borrowing: the compiler is not yet able to understand that this is code is safe. So for the time being (until the so called non-lexical borrowing is implemented), try to rewrite your code. Like this, for example:

```
fn advance_while<P>(&mut self, predicate: P)
    where P: Fn(&I::Item) -> bool 
{
    loop {
        if let Some(val) = self.peek() {
            if !predicate(val) {
                break;
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
        self.next();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite the function into this:

```
impl<I: Iterator> AdvanceWhile<I> for Peekable<I> {
    fn advance_while<P>(&mut self, predicate: P)
        where P: Fn(&I::Item) -> bool 
    {
        loop {
            {
                let peek = match self.peek() {
                    Some(p) => p,
                    None => break,
                };
                if !predicate(peek) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            self.next();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your original code could do this:

```
while let Some(val) = self.peek() {
    if predicate(val) {
        self.next();
        println!("{:?}", val);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Accessing `val` after you called `next()` would allow you to access memory that was no longer valid, causing memory unsafety.

As others have pointed out, your code doesn't *actually* do this, but current Rust uses *lexical lifetimes*, an overly-conservative approximation of how long a reference needs to be valid for. Future Rust should help constrain the logic without introducing unsafety.

---

If your value implements `Copy`, you can make use of that:

```
fn advance_while<P>(&mut self, predicate: P)
where
    P: Fn(&I::Item) -> bool,
    I::Item: Copy,
{
    while let Some(&val) = self.peek() {
        if predicate(&val) {
            self.next();
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This causes the value to be copied from the reference returned by `peek`. Since nothing is borrowed, the fact that you are going to mutate the iterator does not cause a problem.

If your type implements `Clone`, you could clone the value, again disassociating it:

```
fn advance_while<P>(&mut self, predicate: P)
where
    P: Fn(&I::Item) -> bool,
    I::Item: Clone,
{
    while let Some(val) = self.peek().cloned() {
        if predicate(&val) {
            self.next();
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

If your type is neither `Copy` nor `Clone`, you need to introduce a temporary variable for the boolean result. This clearly informs the compiler that the borrow returned by `peek` isn't needed beyond the equality check statement:

```
fn advance_while<P>(&mut self, predicate: P)
where
    P: Fn(&I::Item) -> bool,
{
    while self.peek().map_or(false, &predicate) {
        self.next();
    }
}
```

See also:

- [Rust borrow of a HashMap lasts beyond the scope it's in?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38023871/155423)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so this is not the best way of doing it but it might come in handy for more complicated cases...

```
fn advance_while<P>(&mut self, predicate: P)
    where P: Fn(&I::Item) -> bool 
{
    while {
        if let Some(val) = self.peek() {
            predicate(val)
        } else {
            false
        }
    }
    {
        self.next();
    }
}
```

[Playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4653dc9793acca69c8a3bec8812f8b81&version=nightly&backtrace=0)