# Understanding borrows in a match with an Option

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have a simple parser that can be distilled to something like this:

```
use std::str::Chars;
use std::iter::Peekable;

struct Parser<'a> {
    input: Peekable<Chars<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Parser<'a> {
    fn new(input: &'a str) -> Self {
        Parser {
            input: input.chars().peekable(),
        }
    }

    fn consume(&mut self, check: char) -> bool {
        // see below
    }
}
```

My original implementation of `consume`, which should take a look at the next character in the input and return true (and advance the `Peekable`) if it matches the passed character, was this:

```
fn consume(&mut self, check: char) -> bool {
    match self.input.peek() {
        Some(c) if *c == check => {
            self.input.next();
            true
        },
        _ => false
    }
}
```

The compiler informed me that I can't mutably borrow `self.input` for the call to `next` because I've already borrowed it in the call to `peek`:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `self.input` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:18:17
   |
16 |         match self.input.peek() {
   |               ---------- first mutable borrow occurs here
17 |             Some(c) if *c == check => {
18 |                 self.input.next();
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
...
22 |         }
   |         - first borrow ends here
```

I don't understand why adding a `&` to the `Some` match expression (and dropping the `*` from `*c`) makes the code compile:

```
fn consume(&mut self, check: char) -> bool {
    match self.input.peek() {
        Some(&c) if c == check => {
            self.input.next();
            true
        },
        _ => false
    }
}
```

Based on Boiethios' comment, what would the proper solution be if `c` wasn't `Copy`?

Comment: With `Some(&c)` you drop the reference and make a copy of the char. With `Some(c)` you keep a reference on it, that prevents another borrowing.

Comment: @Boiethios I think I understand, thanks. What would the idiomatic solution be if `c` wasn't marked `Copy`?

Comment: There are different solutions, but for example: `let has_matched = /*etc.*/` and after the `match` block: `if has_matched { self.input.next() }`. When you are stuck, intermediate variable is often a good solution.

Comment: But maybe your design does not fit the Rust paradigm. I cannot confirm that because I am not so much good at Rust, and I have no time currently to investigate this case.

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks — [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47893160/62082) on the duplicated question is the explanation I was looking for (the other answers just show alternatives, which I already explored).

Comment: @MichelleTilley yeah, I originally posted it here, but then I found that older duplicate so I moved my tweaked answer there. That helps explain why it fits so nicely with your specific questions ;-)